# result of a compiled class in Eclipse for Java EE Developers

Tags: eclipse, compilation

I am trying to get the ".class" file from a java class in Eclipse for Java EE developers.

I have enabled the the "build" option in project menu and I am building the project but still can't find the compile file or compilation errors in console window.

Thanks,
Sid

Comment: open the Navigator view and look in the "bin" folder of your project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would wager that your java source file isn't in a location considered as java source directory by Eclipse. Go to project properties -> Java Build Path -> Source and make sure that the folder where you keep your java source is listed. Alternatively, move your java source file under [project]/src directory which is the default java source folder for web projects in Eclipse.

Also, do not look for compilation errors in the console. Eclipse doesn't use javac or similar for compilation. It compiles java source file internally on the fly. Any errors will appear in the Problems view. The compiled class files will appear in the output directory designated in Java Build Path properties. Default output location for web projects is build/classes.

Answer (score 3):

The .class files should be located on `X:/yourWorkspaceLocation/yourProject/build/classes`

Comment: @Jhurtado: Thank you but I cannot find the ".class" file in the folder you mentioned. I understand that it should in this location and for come reason the file is not being compiled, but I cannot see the compilation error either. If I can see the compilation error it can become easier to track down the issue. Thanks,

Comment: Try pressing (Alt+Shift+Q) then Q again to bring the show view window and type console. That should open your console and show you any compilation problems and messages you need.

Comment: @Jhurtado: I can se the console but  there is no error in the console.

Comment: What is it you are trying to compile? a full project? a single .java? a WebApp? also how are you running it? Ctrl + F11? Run As? (Alt+Shift+X)+J? sometimes i've found eclipse won't compile my classes unless i manually click Run -> Run As-> Java Application.

Comment: This is a JSP/Spring Application and When I run it, The main JSP page is rendered but no sign that the class ever got compiled . Here is the class code, this is controller class of a Spring MVC application.

Comment: package com.test.tradingapp.web; import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest; import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse; import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView; import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.Controller; public class PortfolioController implements Controller { public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) { return new ModelAndView("/WEB_INF/jsp/portfolio.jsp"); } }

Comment: sorry the code is very badly formattedbut this is the only way I was able to put the code in comment. I appreciate your help so far.    Thank you.